# Compare 2 Words for Measure of Similarity

Tags: algorithm, similarity, measure

Question:
Is there a possiblity to compare if "Hollændervej" and "Hollaedervej" are similiar except the "ae" and "æ" after or before using Levenshtein algorithm? Is it about some measure of similarity.

This context is about making æ and ae equal depends on what word you retrieve.

Other information:
*Is it easier to compare the word "Økernveien" and "Okernveien" after using Levenshtein algorithm because you the value of the difference that is 1, especially in the beginning of the word.
In order to compare it you just remove the first letter.
It is more difficult compare "Hollændervej" and "Hollaedervej" than "Økernveien" and "Okernveien".

*I believe that you need more than Levenshtein algorithm in order to solve it.

*You also have another words that is "Göteborg" and "Goteborg", "Vårveien", "Varveien" "MARKEDSFØRING", "MARKEDSFORING", "Rhrts vei" and "Røhrts vei", "Sjurs?ya" and "Sjursøya"
It is about letter that is not common letter in every country..

I also want to thanks to the people who provided feedback for improving the content of the information.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to normalize your special characters and their equivalents before comparison? Like replace "æ" with "ae" in both strings before comparing them?

Comment: Look into weighted Levenshtein (edit) distance

Comment: Uwe Allner - yes it is possible to do it

Comment: "Look into weighted Levenshtein (edit) distance" What do you mean, you mean mean edit Levenshtein ?

Comment: Do you want the algorithm to tell you that "Göteborg" and "Goteborg" have a distance of 0 (i.e. that they are equal)?

Comment: Please clarify your question I didn't understand why `Compare to "Hollændervej" and "Hollaedervej", it is a little more difficult.` is actually more difficult than `"Økernveien" and "Okernveien" ` it is just the place where the character differs.

Comment: "Do you want the algorithm to tell you that "Göteborg" and "Goteborg" have a distance of 0 (i.e. that they are equal)?"  Answear: Yes

Comment: SomeDude, I have updated the content and I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some additional work after performing Levenshtein distance. First you apply Levenshtein algorithm to calculate the distance. That will give minimum edits required to transform one string to another. But then you need to keep track of the minimum edit path. Like for example if you are transforming `Hollændervej` to `Hollaedervej` the minimum edit path may look like: del->insert->insert or insert->delete->insert, Basically keep track of characters you deleted, inserted, replaced.

Now you need to have a dictionary of "similar" characters that you think are similar according to the alphabet of the word.
For example `æ` maps to `{a,e}`.
Now check for these special characters in your path.
For example your path looks like : del a -> insert æ -> del e, then you need to look for its adjacent entries ( left = a, right = e  or left = a, left = b or right = a, right = b).
If they match to the contents in your value in dictionary, then there is a similarity and keep checking your path.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_normalization) the words before doing the comparison. This is a fairly common thing to do in string searching. For example, strings are converted to upper- or lower-case, punctuation characters are removed, diacritics are converted to their non-decorated equivalents, etc.

The idea is to have rules that reduce the alphabet that's used. You apply those rules to every word. One rule might be, for example, "change 'ö' to 'o'", or "change 'æ' to 'ae'."

Once you've normalized the strings, you can more easily compare them for "equality."